# AngularJs multiple select shows unresolved list instead of contents in IE

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJs to bind a list of employees into a mult-select tag. Below is my code:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="event.attendees"
        ng-options="c.Email as c.FullName for c in employees" id="eEmployees" multiple style="height:315px !important; -webkit-appearance:listbox !important;">

 </select>
```

The result displayed correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE it shows a list of {{c.FullName}}, instead of the real names. I tried to right-click to view the source in IE (and also IE inspector, F12), but in the source, the employee names display correctly.

Have anyone here ever ran into this issue before? I really have no sense why this happened. I placed my multiple select tag in a modal-dialog, does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by added $scope.$apply() after angular service pulled the list data.  It needs a little delay before binding it.  But I still don't know why this situation only happened in IE though.